# Angular 2 - AoT 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs

from : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

After compiling my project with ngc, I keep getting a 404 on start

```
404 GET /aot/app/app.module.ngfactory
```

if I try to access the resource in the browser it works

```
200 GET /aot/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
```

I dont understand why angular does not add the ".js" extension here

details :

I modified my main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/app/app.module.ngfactory';
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

I compiled with ngc:

```
node_modules\.bin\ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

tsconfig-aot.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },

    "files": [
    "app/app.module.ts",
    "app/main.ts"
  ],

   "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "aot",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
 }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Deleting a post will not lift your question ban. See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583). Also, moderators don't read every comment ever added, I only saw this one because it was flagged by a community member. You can delete this post yourself, there are no answers on it. Posting fake answers is only going to lead to a post ban on answers.